# Laravel Get Values from checkbox 0 turn null

Tags: sql, laravel, checkbox

I have database like this:

[image]

column cek for define checkbox with code like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ ($d->kd == $d->cek ? '0' : '1')  }}" name="ada[]" @if($d->cek) checked @endif>
```

When its checked it will gave value '1', and when its unchecked its supposed to give value '0' but instead '0' i got null. Anyone here how should it? Thank you.

Comment: The value is only sent when the checkbox is checked so your code needs to account for that. This is how checkboxes in forms work.

Comment: then how to write it so I can have value '0' for unchecked and value '1' for checked? ' '

Comment: Whatever you do the value will only be sent with the form when the checkbox is checked so do `value="1"` and then in the backend check which array elements are set and which are missing to determine which ended up being set

Comment: Oh I get it, so I need to make code on controller. Thank you so much. Do you have reference for this one?

Comment: Read the notes at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: okay, thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ ($d->kd == $d->cek ? '0' : '1')  }}" 
name="ada[]" @if($d->kd == '1') checked @endif >
```

Comment: Still null. It seems the value is only sent when the checkbox is checked, but I need return value if checkbox unchecked too...

Comment: @DearJanice when unchecked, a checkbox never gets posted. thats how checkboxes work...

Comment: Thank you. Instead of checkbox what should I use to have what I need? I need value '0' for unchecked and value '1' for checked... ' '

Comment: @DearJanice if you get 1 controller then store it else if it is null or doesn't exist then store 0

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ ($d->kd == $d->cek ? '0' : '1')  }}" name="ada[]" @if($d->kd == '1' ? 'checked' : '')@endif>
```

Comment: it still turn null, when unchecked